# STM32F405 bxCan does not leave init mode

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, can-bus

When I try to init bxCan on STM32F405 MCU, it does not set `CAN_MSR_INAK` after leaving request.

Here is my code:

```
rcc_peripheral_enable_clock(&RCC_APB1ENR, RCC_APB1ENR_CAN2EN);
nvic_enable_irq(NVIC_CAN2_RX0_IRQ);
can_reset(CAN2);
if (can_init(CAN2,          // Can
        false,              // Time triggered communication mode
        true,               // Automatic bus-off management
        true,               // Automatic wakeup mode
        false,              // No automatic retransmission
        false,              // Receive FIFO locked mode
        true,               // Transmit FIFO priority
        CAN_BTR_SJW_1TQ,    // Resynchronization time quanta jump width
        CAN_BTR_TS1_11TQ,   // Time segment 1 time quanta width
        CAN_BTR_TS2_2TQ,    // Time segment 2 time quanta width
        3,                  // Baud rate prescaler (1 mbps)
        false,              // Loopback
        false) != 0)        // Silent mode
    _exit(0);
```

And here is `can_init` function:

```
int can_init(uint32_t canport, bool ttcm, bool abom, bool awum, bool nart,
         bool rflm, bool txfp, uint32_t sjw, uint32_t ts1, uint32_t ts2,
         uint32_t brp, bool loopback, bool silent)
{
    volatile uint32_t wait_ack;
    int ret = 0;

    /* Exit from sleep mode. */
    CAN_MCR(canport) &= ~CAN_MCR_SLEEP;

    /* Request initialization "enter". */
    CAN_MCR(canport) |= CAN_MCR_INRQ;

    /* Wait for acknowledge. */
    wait_ack = CAN_MSR_INAK_TIMEOUT;
    while ((--wait_ack) &&
        ((CAN_MSR(canport) & CAN_MSR_INAK) != CAN_MSR_INAK));

    /* Check the acknowledge. */
    if ((CAN_MSR(canport) & CAN_MSR_INAK) != CAN_MSR_INAK) {
        return 1;
    }

    /* clear can timing bits */
    CAN_BTR(canport) = 0;

    /* Set the automatic bus-off management. */
    if (ttcm) {
        CAN_MCR(canport) |= CAN_MCR_TTCM;
    } else {
        CAN_MCR(canport) &= ~CAN_MCR_TTCM;
    }

    if (abom) {
        CAN_MCR(canport) |= CAN_MCR_ABOM;
    } else {
        CAN_MCR(canport) &= ~CAN_MCR_ABOM;
    }

    if (awum) {
        CAN_MCR(canport) |= CAN_MCR_AWUM;
    } else {
        CAN_MCR(canport) &= ~CAN_MCR_AWUM;
    }

    if (nart) {
        CAN_MCR(canport) |= CAN_MCR_NART;
    } else {
        CAN_MCR(canport) &= ~CAN_MCR_NART;
    }

    if (rflm) {
        CAN_MCR(canport) |= CAN_MCR_RFLM;
    } else {
        CAN_MCR(canport) &= ~CAN_MCR_RFLM;
    }

    if (txfp) {
        CAN_MCR(canport) |= CAN_MCR_TXFP;
    } else {
        CAN_MCR(canport) &= ~CAN_MCR_TXFP;
    }

    if (silent) {
        CAN_BTR(canport) |= CAN_BTR_SILM;
    } else {
        CAN_BTR(canport) &= ~CAN_BTR_SILM;
    }

    if (loopback) {
        CAN_BTR(canport) |= CAN_BTR_LBKM;
    } else {
        CAN_BTR(canport) &= ~CAN_BTR_LBKM;
    }

    /* Set bit timings. */
    CAN_BTR(canport) |= sjw | ts2 | ts1 |
        ((brp - 1ul) & CAN_BTR_BRP_MASK);

    /* Request initialization "leave". */
    CAN_MCR(canport) &= ~CAN_MCR_INRQ;

    /* Wait for acknowledge. */
    wait_ack = CAN_MSR_INAK_TIMEOUT;
    while ((--wait_ack) &&
           ((CAN_MSR(canport) & CAN_MSR_INAK) == CAN_MSR_INAK));

    if ((CAN_MSR(canport) & CAN_MSR_INAK) == CAN_MSR_INAK) {
        ret = 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

So, this function successfully enters init mode, but can't leave it.

I tried to do following things:

- Init CAN1 instead of CAN2
- Set up different clock frequencies
- Set up different settings of can
- Do and do not configure can pins

and nothing had any effect. It always fails at the same point.

Also (just to be sure), I tried to disable bxCan clock - and then can can't even enter init mode (as expected).

The same code works perfectly for STM32F103, so I don't know, what can be wrong.

Comment: What's the "wait_ack" thing supposed to do? How can you know that the loop won't finish before the hardware got a chance to set the flag? If you need a timeout, you should do a professional solution with a hardware timer. During debugging, you probably want to wait "for ever".

Comment: I peeked at the manual: "The software clears this bit to switch the hardware into normal mode. Once 11 consecutive recessive bits have been monitored on the Rx signal the CAN hardware is synchronized and ready for transmission and reception.". So depending on your baudrate, this could be a bit of time. If your CPU is running on a fast clock, it may have finished that down-counting loop long before those 11 bits. What happens if you just wait forever for the flag to be set?

Comment: `can_init` is the part of libopencm3 library, so this function I didn't write.  
Normally, it has to finish in couple ticks, not 65535 (CAN_MSR_INAK_TIMEOUT).

Anyway, instead of `_exit(0);` i tried to put 
`while ((CAN_MSR(CAN2) & CAN_MSR_INAK) == CAN_MSR_INAK);`  
and it has no effect either - it just loops forever.

Comment: It doesn't matter who wrote it, it is sloppily written, fishy code that wouldn't pass any half-decent code review. But then of course most "open-blabla-download-from-github" is crap. Suppose you set the baudrate to 10kbps which is a standard CAN baudrate. 11*1/10kbps = 1.1ms. Given that much time, your CPU can probably down-count from 65535 to 0 a thousand times over.

Comment: I agree that quality of this code is questionably, but the point is that it's not the source of my problem.

Comment: Stupid question: is there a CAN bus present? As in, do you have a transceiver and are the CAN lines kept in a recessive state with no bus errors present?

Comment: Yes and yes. Also, if I load firmware with another implementation (RTOS-based), it does work. Sadly, but RTOS doesn't fit my needs. Also I didn't found any big differences in CAN setup between libopencm3 and RTOS.

Answer (score 2):

Check for these parameters:
(i) Check CAN clock is enabled (since you are entering init mode, this seems fine.)
(ii)Check if CAN GPIO port clock is enabled (before entering can init mode you should enable this)
(iii) Check if Can GPIO pins are configured (before entering can init mode you should configure this)

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer (although problem is already solved).
It turned out that the problem was in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when used silent loopback mode. The solution was to pull up RX pin so it could  receive 11 recessive bits while changing a mode from "Initialization mode" to "Normal mode".

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured pins correctly? I think F405 needs alternative mapping in GPIO config